# jQuery: Anchor loads page and then scrolls to div

Tags: jquery, onload, scrollto

I have a one page website which scrolls to the correct section when a navigation link it clicked - Please see http://www.cleanupbritain.org for a live example.

I am now extending the website and adding a blog which is located in a subdirectory, I am trying to setup the blogs navigation to load www.cleanupbritain.org and then scroll to the correct section. Is this possible? I am fairly new to jQuery so any help would be great appreciated.

Here is the navigation link:

```
<a href="http://www.cleanupbritain.org" onClick="goToByScroll('news')">News</a>
```

And here is the script I have written:

```
<!-- ScrollTo for navigation scrolling -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    function goToByScroll(id){
            jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top - 236},'slow');
    }
    function goToTop(){
            jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0},'slow');
        }
});
</script>
```

I presume the navigation link is not right, but I am not sure what needs to be changed to ensure the script is executed at the right time?

Many thanks in advance for your help,

Lewis.

Answer (score 6):

The navigation link should say `<a href="http://www.cleanupbritain.org/#news">News</a>`

Now if the news block has an `id="news"`, the browser will scroll to it automatically -- that's what anchors are made for. If you'd like an animation, then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    function goToByScroll(id){
       jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top - 236},'slow');
    }

    if(window.location.hash != '') {
        goToByScroll(window.location.hash.substr(1));        
});
</script>
```

Maybe you'll have to change the news' block id to prevent automatic anchor behavior, but you should test.

Comment: Thanks Andr, the anchor using the ID works perfectly but the script doesn't seem to have any effect at all, the browser jumps to the bottom of the <div> without animation and forgets the top offset, any ideas? Thanks in advance! Lewis

Comment: I'll repeat the last line: "Maybe you'll have to change the news' block id to prevent automatic anchor behavior, but you should test." For example, the link ends with "#news", but the div has id="news-scroll". Then in the script: goToByScroll(window.location.hash.substr(1) + '-scroll');

Comment: Andr how will this prevent automatic anchor behavior? Also this will mean I will have to add "-scroll" to multiple ID's on the page which isn't ideal.. even with the suggested script and change of ID the browser still jumps to the bottom of the <div> and ignores the animation and offset - Sorry I am literally learning JS so not too familiar with the language or jQuery framework. Lewis

Comment: It will prevent the default anchor behavior because the id is "news-scroll" and the link says "#news" — they are different.

Comment: Ahh sorry I misunderstood your instructions, I didn't quite grasp that you were suggeting trying different section id / link, this does indeed prevent default browser behavior but sadly the window does not scroll at all. Getting there!

Comment: Didn't think about it earlier, but i'm not sure if "animate" will help you at all. Usually I use scrollTo plugin to do this kind of stuff: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: How are you doing, did it help?